# How to pass in class type to method for Gson

Tags: java

All,

I would like to pass in a class type as a variable, and use it to parametrize a list. For instance, I have my method as follows:

```
public void index(String url, Class clazz) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<clazz>>(){}.getType();
    gson.fromJson(response.body().toString(), listType);
}
```

Is this even possible? Note that in this case, I can't use generics.

Answer (score 2):

`Class` is a raw type. Use it with a type parameter defined in a generic method and use that type parameter:

```
public <T> void index(String url, Class<T> clazz) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<T>>(){}.getType();
    gson.fromJson(response.body().toString(), listType);
}
```

Comment: Note that the clazz argument is useless (and unused).

Comment: @JBNizet: clazz argument is still needed because the method return VOID. If the method return T or List<T> for example, clazz argument will not be needed in that cases

Comment: @Loc It should compile fine without the `Class` parameter. JB's point is that the current parameter is not used. I edited a little bit my answer.

Comment: OP likely needs to use `clazz` in the method body.

Comment: @manouti: If clazz is not defined. No error compile, No runtime error - seem correct BUT at runtime, Java does not know what exactly generic T is. This is why clazz is still needed.

Comment: @manouti I don't think I can use generics in this case. I need to deserialize the object with Gson. In an effort to write a simple question, I stripped it of too many specifics. Please see the edited question if you have a moment.